# Starting a runnable in the MainActivity

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a runnable in `audioService.java` where it does a certain task. The runnable in the service and I start the runnable inside the service.

```
AudioService.java

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    new Thread(new audioRunnable()).start(); //starting the thread
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public class audioRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
        public void run() {
      // task has been carried out
  }
}
```

I start the service in the MainActivity like this

```
@Override
Protected void onCreate(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, audioService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Is this the right approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `runOnUiThread()`, just execute:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, audioService.class);
startService(intent);
```

within the `OnClickListener#onClick` set on your button.

This will start up the service and inside your service you have already created a new thread (non ui thread) to do `// task has been carried out`.

BTW, consider `IntentService` and override `onHandleIntent`, and do `// task has been carried out` in this method, this will automatically be done in a worker thread.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I know that my thread will be started if i start the service. I am just looking for way to start my thread separately. Maybe send a message from service to start.

Comment: Not understood, your thread has already been in a separated thread.

Comment: LiuWenbin, Since I am new to android. I misunderstood the concept. you were right. Thanks once again.

Comment: @cantona_7 glad if it helped you :)